# How do I implement `parsec` for conduits?

Tags: haskell

I have written a `Conduit` that generates a stream of items. These items have a customized type (let's say `Record`) and each contains some structured data. I am trying to write a downstream `Conduit` that parses the `Record`-stream.

Interestingly I find many concepts in the [parsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec) package make sense in my application. For example, I sometimes expect `many` records that `satisfy` a particular predicate to come in a row, or perhaps I expect exactly one instance of a particular record comes right after exactly one other particular record. So I was seeking ways to reimplement those functions for `Conduit`s for example,

```
satisfy :: Monad m => (r -> Bool) -> ConduitM r a m rp
many :: Monad m => ConduitM r a m rp -> ConduitM r a m [rp]
sepBy :: Monad m => ConduitM r a m rp -> ConduitM r a m sep -> ConduitM r a m [rp]
```

which specializes to these in the above example

```
satisfy :: (Record -> Bool) -> ConduitM Record () IO Record
many :: ConduitM Record () IO Record -> ConduitM Record () IO [Record]
sepBy :: ConduitM Record () IO Record -> ConduitM Record () IO Record -> ConduitM Record a IO [Record]
```

so that I can write neat code like:

```
parserC :: Sink Record IO (Record, [Record], [Record])
parserC = do
    red <- satisfy isRecordRed
    blues <- many $ satisfy isRecordBlue
    assorted <- anyRecord `sepBy` satisfy isRecordPurple
    return (red, blues, assorted)
```

Now looking at the documentation of parsec, I found that these functions are in fact defined for very generic `Stream` class. So I think hooking onto the package should be possible. However, one difficulty I ran into is that `parse` function work with the entirety of the stream `s`. Is there a way to parse a `parsecT` in a stream-lined way?

Comment: No, there is no way to make `parsec` do anything streamy. `attoparsec`, on the other hand, has a great interface for that. Don't miss the `parseWith` function, which is how you probably want to run your parsers most of the time (it lets you avoid ever worrying about partial results).

Comment: @dfeuer: Thanks. I'm looking into the possibility of using `attoparsec`. `Data.Attoparsec.Combinator` seems promising since it's generic, however, `parseWith` is in `Data.Attoparsec.ByteString` and thus is restricted to `ByteString`.

Comment: You're welcome to write your own parsing library. It could be great! I don't know if there's anything out there for that right now. The generic combinators are useful even when not using `attoparsec` parsers.

Comment: @dfeuer: After looking closely at the implementations of [`Data.Attoparsec.ByteString`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.1.6/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html) functions, I think it is possible. I need to reimplement `advance`(internal), `peekItem`, `satisfy`, and also a generic `parse`.

Comment: Oh, before you go too far, you should see if [Data.Conduit.Attoparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.9.1/docs/Data-Conduit-Attoparsec.html) helps you.

Comment: And why are you parsing things other than `ByteString` and `Text`?

Comment: @dfeuer: Because unfortunately I'm working with a third-party package that only has a `get1 :: IO (Maybe Record)` retriever API. And the `Record`s retrieved follow a somewhat complicated pattern.

Comment: I stumbled upon a package that might be what you're looking for: [incremental-parser](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/incremental-parser-0.2.3.4/docs/Text-ParserCombinators-Incremental.html). Binding it to `Conduit` shouldn't be difficult.

Comment: Can you not implement a Stream instance for conduit?